# After Switching IDE to AHCI Ubuntu Installs But Won't Boot

Tags: ide, ahci

So, after switching IDE to AHCI Ubuntu 16.04.03 installs fine, but won't boot. Just stays on purple screen.

Here is my [BootInfo summary](https://paste2.org/DzkH2B3m).

Comment: A [similar issue](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254288) was fixed in Ubuntu Forums a few years ago with the help of [oldfred](https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred).

Comment: Oldfred does not know about btrfs. And that may be part of the issue. If you really want btrfs, I might then use a /boot partition that is ext4 and then all data in btrfs. Redhat is depreciating btrfs. And others have had issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the BTRFS file system that was causing the problem.

As soon as I switched to EXT4 and made a separate /boot partition, the problem disappeared.